Joblib Parallel in Sagemaker Studio Classic does not work
I am using a heavy instance (ml.C5.24xlarge) on AWS Sagemaker and I am trying to parallelize a loop.
results = Parallel(n_jobs=90, backend='multiprocessing', verbose=1)(delayed(process_data)(pair) for pair in data_list[0:10])

Even when processing only 10 data from my list of data, the execution time is long. On a local machine this takes minutes.
Also, the kernel and instance CPU/MEM usage is as it is shown in the figure below.
How can verify that the parallelization works?

